# Can a field data type change from row to row when using OracleDatareader

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, plsql

When using `OracleDataReader` (`Oracle.DataAccess.Client`) in a c# program to read data from a recordset are there any situations where the data type in one of the fields could change from row to row ( except `DBNull` ).

I am thinking of situations like where the select uses a case statement that can return either a value from a column that is a number(9) or a value from a column that is defined as a number(14).

Are there any other gotcha's that might be relevant when up casting the value returned when using the indexer on the data reader e.g. `int cityId = (int)dataReader["CityId"];` (except handling DBNull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each column in the result set will have the same data type and length/size/precision. JDBC connections

Using JDBC, these can actually be obtained from the [result set metadata](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jdbc/OracleResultSetMetaData.html). Not sure whether there is an equivalent for C#

One oddity is a very special user defined type called SYS.ANYTYPE which is mostly used internally for replication. You can have three rows in a result set with one column. The data type of the column would be SYS.ANYTYPE but internally one could have a date value while another has a number and the last has a character. There are special packages for determining what is hidden inside any ANYTYPE value.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, data type doesn't change on a row by row basis.

If the query uses a case statement that returns values from different data-types, the engine is responsible to pick the most appropriate to hold values for all, and it will describe the result-set using that data type, as the standard forces to use one data type per column in any result set.

Anyway, if you can't trust/know the source of the query, surround your cast in a try/catch sentence to get any unexpected result and act accordingly.

Comment: Data types not changing on a row by row basis is what generally I thought.  But then consider a number(9) that can be null.  For one row the value might be set so in .net the data type for that row will be an int.  For another row the value might be null, the data type for that row will be System.DBNull.  Therefore that proves that the representation of the value coming from the db on the .net side can have different data types int or DBNull.  So this got me thinking that if technically the data type could be either int or DBNull then maybe technically it could even be something else.

Comment: @Phil Carson - I think you are confusing 'value' with 'type' here. When a particular row returns NULL for that column's value, it is a value - the column did not change type. Just as when the row returns 9 for a particular column, it is returning the value, not the type. The column could be INT, or SMALLINT, or BIGINT, but the value is 9. Likewise, the *value* can be NULL, but the column retains it's type. .NET performs some work "under the hood" to map the values to CLR types, and it has special logic for NULL values. This may be causing the confusion.